# Disable lights on Netgear WNDR4300 running DDWRT

Tags: dd-wrt

My router is in my bedroom, and I would like to disable the lights on the front.  How can I do that?  Im quite new to this, so please explain in detail.

Comment: If there is not an option within the configuration page for the device, then the option does not exist, and you will have to resort to the low technical solution of black masking tape.

Comment: It will be an nv_ram option specific to this model router, usually a hex number referring to a GPIO on the router-motherboard... Good luck figuring out the values!

Answer (score 1):

Use insulating tape - less than a buck/quid/euro from any DIY store.

Use a matching colour if you want to be subtle, or black if you just want rid of the lights altogether. You can use multiple layers to dim them but not eliminate entirely. No longer disturbing, but you can still tell they're working…

[image]